# Generate random reqId for concurrent requests in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, logging, uuid, access-log

I am trying to generate random requestId for my express server. I have been using uuidV1() from 
node-uuid module. It's working fine for the normal requests but when i'm trying to loadtest it using concurrent requests. the generated value is same.

```
const uuidv1 = require("uuid/v1");    
const reqId  = uuidv1()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generate it in a middleware and attach it to the request object. Secondly uuidv1 generates ids based on timestamps(check wiki [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), use v4 instead. 
following is the express example.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");    

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.reqId = uuidv4();
    next();
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
  res.send(`Hello World! with reqId: ${req.reqId}`);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Comment: on using loadtest npm module with, it generate same uuid if you'll put concurrency to more than 1. example: loadtest -n 10 -c 5, in this way the generated reqId is coming duplicate

Comment: putting some snippets of how you are using this(your web server). would be helpful in order to answer

Comment: for above example I loadtest it using `ab -n 20 -c 15 http://localhost:3000/`. which is sending 15 concurrent request, and I saw no duplication in reqId. If you are using mac ab(apache benchmark) should be installed by default

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uuid module. you can use below module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

With this you can generate unique id based on combination of mac address, process id and timestamp

Comment: The problem still persisting with this with >=5 concurrent requests

Answer (score 0):

The 'express-request-id' npm module should do the work for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-id

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const addRequestId = require('express-request-id')();  

app.use(addRequestId);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
  res.send(`Request Id : ${req.id}`);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 3000')
});
```